# qt setStylesheet does not update

Tags: qt

I want to change the borders of my textboxes if they are not field. So I do a simple check and the change styles like this:

```
if(!ui->TextBoxPhone->text().isEmpty() && !ui->TextBoxAddress->text().isEmpty()) {
    cout<<"Saved fine \n";
}
else {
    if(ui->TextBoxPhone->text().isEmpty()) {
        ui->TextBoxPhone->setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid red");
    }
    if(ui->TextBoxAddress->text().isEmpty()) {
        ui->TextBoxAddress->setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid red");
    }
}
```

So the problem I have is that the stylesheet would not update automaticly. It will update however if I click elsewhere.
I already tried using

```
ui->TextBoxName->style()->unpolish(ui->TextBoxName);
ui->TextBoxName->style()->polish(ui->TextBoxName);
ui->TextBoxName->update();
```

No luck. Might it be a macbook isue?

here are some screenshots:

as you can see left-border is red

[image]

when I click on another textbox both of them update and become red

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it... repaint() method did the job;

```
 ui->TextBoxPhone->repaint();
```

Comment: `update()` probably better here since means that Qt schedules the repaint efficiently once has returned to the event loop rather than painting immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
myTextEdit->setStyleSheet("QTextEdit{background: transparent; border: none;}");
```

Nothing else needed. Make sure to specify correct type for the stylesheet. Or maybe even this will resolve:

```
myTextEdit->setStyleSheet("{background: transparent; border: none;}");
```